# @PersistenceUnit is not working (Java EE 7, Glassfish 4.1)

Tags: java, persistence, jta, glassfish-4

I use the annotation @PersistenceUnit to obtain an instance of a EntityManagerFactory but after several tests, it doesn't work. I have been searching for the theory, examples, etc., but without success. The theory seems easy but I not able to see where is the problem with my code, or what is missing.

The code of the bean that I'm using is:

```
import ...

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TopBean extends UserTransactionWrapper implements TopService
{

    @Inject
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="puTop")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    public OperationResult<Boolean> retrieve()
    {
        return execute();
    }

    protected OperationResult<Boolean> doRetrieve()
                                                                                 throws Exception
    {
            OperationResult<Boolean> operationResult = new OperationResult<Boolean>();
            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

            long id = 5;
            Node node = new Node(id, "Host.One", NodeType.SWITCH, true);
            entityManager.persist(node);
            operationResult.setData(node.getId() == id);

            return operationResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected Logger getLogger()
    {
        return logger;
    }

}
```

The UserTransactionWrapper class only contains the code that initializes the user transaction that is obtained by the function:

```
private UserTransaction getTransaction()
                                                                    throws NamingException
{
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    return (UserTransaction)context.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
}
```

The injection of the user transaction with @Resource doesn't work, so I had to do it that way.

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="puTop" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/Top</jta-data-source>
        <class>...</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thank you in advance!

Manu

I'm adding the code of the UserTransactionWrapper class:

```
public abstract class UserTransactionWrapper extends Wrapper
{

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <E> OperationResult<E> execute(Object... parameters)
    {
        OperationResult<E> operationResult = new OperationResult<E>();
        Method doMethod = findMethod();
        Logger logger = getLogger();
    // If the method exists...
        if (doMethod != null)
        {
            UserTransaction userTransaction = null; 
            try
            {

            // Initializing user transaction
            // =============================

                userTransaction = getTransaction();
                userTransaction.begin();

            // Accomplishment of the operation
            // ===============================

                int parametersN = (parameters != null ? parameters.length : 0);
                Object[] auxiliary = new Object[parametersN];
                for (int i = parametersN; (--i) >= 0;) auxiliary[i] = parameters[i];

                doMethod.setAccessible(true);
                operationResult = (OperationResult<E>)doMethod.invoke(this, auxiliary);

            // Completion of the transaction
            // =============================

                userTransaction.commit();

            }
            catch (Exception primary)
            {
                try
                {
                // If transaction is defined...
                    if (userTransaction != null) userTransaction.rollback();

                    boolean invocationError = primary instanceof InvocationTargetException; 
                // If the invoked method has thrown an exception...
                    if (invocationError)
                    {
                        Throwable cause = primary.getCause();
                        cause = (cause != null ? cause : primary);
                        operationResult.setError(cause);
                        logger.error(INVOCATION_ERROR, cause);
                    }
                // If it hasn't done...
                    else
                    {
                        operationResult.setError(primary);
                        logger.error(UNEXPECTED_ERROR, primary);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception secondary)
                {
                    logger.error(UNEXPECTED_ERROR, secondary);
                }
            }
        }
    // If it doesn't exist...
        else
        {
            operationResult = new OperationResult<E>();
            operationResult.setError(new NoSuchMethodException());
        }

        return operationResult;
    }

    private UserTransaction getTransaction()
                                                                        throws NamingException
    {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        return (UserTransaction)context.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are trying to inject a `EntityManagerFactory`, but you have to inject the `EntityManager` instead when using JTA.

Change your code to look like this:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="puTop")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and use the `EntityManager` directly.

If you instead want to use transaction-type "RESOURCE_LOCAL" then change your `persistence.xml` to the following:

```
<persistence-unit name="puTop" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Anyway, there is no reason to do this manual transaction management. 
You can just write your code like this:

```
@Stateless
public class TopBean
{
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="puTop")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Node persist() {

        Node node = new Node(5, "Host.One", NodeType.SWITCH, true);
        entityManager.persist(node);
        return node;
    }
}
```

That is everything you need to persist an entity...

Comment: I think it is not a solution according to the theory. I have tested it and it doesn't work. See this [link](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/container-vs-application-managed-entitymanager).

Comment: Please read your link again...you are not using transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL".

Comment: If I'm reading the tutorial correctly, the proposed code for _Valid Application Managed Persistence Context usage with BMT_ uses a JTA transaction-type.

Comment: I have added the code of the class UserTransactionWrapper to the original question. In it you can see how the transaction is initialized in the same way of the solution proposed in the tutorial.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do...see my update.

Comment: I had a library based on JTA (UserTransaction), DataSources, DAOS working correctly in which the aplication was responsible of the control and use of the transactions. I want to update the library with modern code, replacing the DAO approach with persistence. I need to mantain the control over the transactions programatically.